# React JS - produce list of divs from JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a React class, which takes in a JSON array and should produce a set of divs:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Maps.css";
import df3 from "./data/df3.json"
import sample from "./data/sample.json"


class Maps extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const data = df3;
    this.state = data
  }

  render()

  {
    var df4 = df3["ds"]
    var d1 = '';
    for (var key in df4)
    {
       var host = df4[key];
       d1 += '<div class="'+key+'" value="'+host[0]+'"/>';
    }

    return (

      <div id="Maps">

         </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Maps
```

So far, it is not returning the set of divs.

Here is the JSON:

```
{"ds":[{
  "s1": {
    "0": 0.0,
    "1": 2.0,
    "2": 0.0,
}
  "s1": {
    "0": 0.0,
    "1": 2.0,
    "2": 0.0,
}
  "s3": {
    "0": 2.0,
    "1": 2.0,
    "2": 0.0,
}}]}
```

which, when fed to the class, should output the following divs:

```
<div class="s1" value="0"/><div class="s2" value="0"/><div class="s3" value="2"/>
```

but I'm not sure how to return it, and when i console log d1, i get:

```
<div class="0" value="undefined"/>
```

any ideas, as always, are helpful!

Comment: You need to use the map instant of for loop.

Comment: could you explain a little more?

Comment: In addition to that, once `d1` holds the array of divs, you need to put `{d1}` in the rendered output

Answer (score 2):

Your render method does not return anything but an empty div.

A correct example would be:

```
render() {
    const myArray = df3["ds"];
    return myArray.map(item => (
        Object.keys(item).map(key => (
            <div key={key} className={key} value={item[key]["0"]} /> 
        )
    ))
}
```

Comment: what i really want is the first value in the sub nodes.  s1 should have a value of 0, s2 should have value of 0, s3 should have value of 2

Comment: Just updated my comment. It should be now what you are looking for!

Comment: Each "key" is equal to "s1", "s2", "s3"
Each item[key]["0"] is equal to 0.0, 0.0, 2.0